# Text-to-Speech Function not working

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

The Android does not talk despite my code being error free and accurate. I have used a toast function to see where the issue occurs. However, both toasts are called.

I have removed all irrelevant code.

The code below is mostly relevant.

```
package com.example.android.BluetoothChat;


import android.R.string;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{
    Button start, stop;
    TextView tv;
    TextView tv2;
    TextView sum;
    LocationManager lm;
    static TextToSpeech Talker;
    TextView myLabel;
    Handler mhandler = new Handler();
    int i;
    int sum1 = 0;
    static BluetoothDevice mmDevice;
    static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    static BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    String lat;
    String lon;

    EditText myTextbox;
    static OutputStream mmOutputStream;
    static InputStream mmInputStream;
    static Thread workerThread;
    static byte[] readBuffer;
    static int readBufferPosition;
    static int counter;
    static volatile boolean stopWorker;
    TextToSpeech talker;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        setTitle("Seizure Detection Helmet Application");

        myTextbox = (EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.name);
        talker = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(),new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override

            public void onInit(int status) {
                if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR)
                {
                talker.setLanguage(Locale.US);
                }

            }
        });
        Button talk = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.talk);
        talk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                speakOut();
            }

        });


    public void speakOut()

    {
        String toSpeak = myTextbox.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String full = ("My name is"+toSpeak+ "and I am having a Seizure at  38.901 Latitude and -77.031 Longitude ");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toSpeak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        talker.speak(full, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), full, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        talker.speak("HELLO",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }


}
```

Comment: Which version device you are testing on ?

Comment: Oh does that matter? I tested it on the Galaxy S2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. You should check for error returned by `setLanguage`. You cannot call `speakOut` until `onInit` has been called. One way you can insure this is to disable the talk button in the xml layout file and enable it in `onInit`.

Comment: I don't have an error returned by setLanguage. What is the issue with setLanguage? How do I call onInit?

Comment: You do not call onInit, it is a callback that will be called when you create the TextToSpeech object. Just disable the talk button in the layout xml and in onInit after setLanguage put talk.setEnabled(true)